# spinnaker installation issue due to dl.bintray.com decommission

Tags: spinnaker

I was trying to setup spinnaker on Ubuntu 18.04 but it failed due because it is not able to download spinnaker dependent packages from dl.bintray.com. I think Jfrog decommissioned the dl.bintray.com which causing this issue.

Error Message:

https://dl.bintray.com/spinnaker-releases/debians bionic InRelease
403  Forbidden [IP: 52.40.65.167 443]
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/spinnaker-releases/debians/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.40.65.167 443]

Is there any other repository to download these packages? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is an open issue for it at https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.io/issues/129 but it has not been resolved.